# implementing voting using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web2py

I am trying to implement the voting to posts in my website using the ajax callback but could it do it.I found that my ajax function is not being called when I pressed  the button.Please can any one help me figure out where I have done the mistake?This is the first time I am using an ajax call-back.

```
<td>
  <button data-direction="down">-</button>
</td>
<td><span class='votes'>{{=recipe.votes}}</span></td>
<td>
  <button data-direction="up">+</button>
</td>
<td>
  <strong>{{=A("comments",_href=URL('view_posts',args=recipe.id))}},{{=recipe.name}}</strong>
</td>
<script>
    function do_ajax_vote(t.direction) {
        alert("clicked");
    }

    jQuery(function () {
        jQuery('[data-direction=up').click(function () {
            do_ajax_vote(this,'up');
        });
        jQuery('[data-direction=down').click(function () {
            do_ajax_vote(this,'down');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `do_ajax_vote` declaration: `t.direction`. Dot not allowed at function attributes part. Use `direction`.

```
function do_ajax_vote(direction) {
    alert(direction + "clicked");
}
```

And change invocation like this:

```
jQuery('[data-direction=down').click(function () {
    do_ajax_vote('down');
});
```